# Substraction string on string and multiply by int role

Tags: c++, string, operator-keyword

I am having issue to understand this code. The goal is to add the sum of all digit from a number until there is only 1 digit recursively

```
long long superDigit(string n, int k) {
   if (n.size() == 1)
         return stoi(n);
    


  long long sum = 0;

  for (int i = 0 ; i <   n.size() ; i++)
  sum += (n[i] - '0') * k;

 return  superDigit(to_string(sum),1);

}
```

However, i don't understand this line
`sum += (n[i] - '0') * k;`

n is a string k is an integer what to expect from this kind of multiplication ?
Moreover i tested the operator - on string and i don't get how it works.

Comment: The only way to know is to ask whoever wrote this code. Only they would know the reason for that. As far as subtraction goes, see what you get when you try `'5'-'0'` or `'7'-'0'`, the reason for the subtraction should then become obvious.

Comment: `(n[i] - '0')` should be an integer from 0 to 9 if n[i] is between '0' and '9'. Note that '0' is not equal to 0.

Answer (score 2):

Every character has a numerical value. You can find these values on the [ASCII Table](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:ASCII-Table.svg). The characters 0-9 are placed in a contiguous chunk on the ASCII table, with 0 at 48 and 9 and 57. So, when you do a char minus `'0'`, you get how far away it is from `'0'` on the ASCII table, effectively converting the character to its corresponding number. `'0' - '0'` is 0 since they're the same character, `'1' - '0'` is 1 since 1 is right next to 0 (49 - 48), `'2' - '0'` is 2 since it's 2 away (50 - 48 = 2), and so on.

Comment: So instead of (n[i] - '0') i could have simply write int(n[i]) ?

Comment: This isn't python; `int` is not a function and casts are formatted `(int) n[i]`, not `int(n[i])`. This would cast the character to its ascii value, which means `(int) '0'` is 48, and `(int) '1'` is 49, and so on, which is not what you want.